# Any good multimethod implementation for Java?

Tags: java, multimethod

I am wondering if there is any reasonably good multimethod implementation/library for Java like Lisp has.

I've found just this apparently frozen one: [JMMF](http://www-igm.univ-mlv.fr/~forax/works/jmmf/)

Answer (score 3):

You could use Clojure which runs on the JVM and has built-in support for multimethods.

Answer (score 2):

I created [this library](https://bitbucket.org/lshift/java-multimethods/) which allows you to implement a Java interface using multimethods, by creating a proxy that satisfies the interface. I'm using it in a few projects and it's reasonably predictable, but read the documentation: Multimethods in Java can behave strangely.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few valid alternatives to deal with the [multiple dispatch problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch), and perhaps these alternatives pretty much justify why it has not been implemented in the language. So, you can use the classical [visitor pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern) or you can use certain amount of reflection.

There is an outdated [MultiJava Project](http://multijava.sourceforge.net/) that implemented mutiple dispatch support in Java and there are a couple of other projects out there using reflection to support multimethods in Java: Java [Multimethods](http://www.lshift.net/blog/2006/06/23/multimethods-for-java), [Java Multimethods Framework](http://igm.univ-mlv.fr/~forax/works/jmmf/). Perhaps there are even more.

You could also consider an alternative Java-based language which does support multimethods, like [Clojure](http://clojure.org/multimethods) or [Groovy](https://blogs.oracle.com/sundararajan/entry/multimethods_in_groovy) (these links point to examples).